# Why does water not fall out of a pressurized tank?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Would water fall out of a pressurized container or not? I'm guessing it would because the internal pressure would cause the water to rush out of the container.

A capped container contains water under pressure.  The container is then uncapped. What happens?  I'm guessing water would rush out of the container.

But I was asked why water *doesn't* come out of the pressurized container.

Comment: Write in small letters. Question with all caps is considered rude and question might get deleted.

Comment: Wouldn't the container need to be sealed in order for it to be pressurized?

Comment: It isn't unclear.  I know what he means.

Comment: Soda bottles are pressurized, no soda flows out open or closed (unless you shake it, of course).

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't know about you, but when I hear the words, "pressurized container", I'm thinking that the pressure inside the container is greater than the pressure outside the container.  By that standard, an open soda bottle (or any other open container) can not be called "pressurized."

Comment: The OP really does need to clarify the questions.  An open container with water in it, to a height of "h", is pressurized.  The pressure is supposedly atmospheric at the top surface of the water, and that pressure linearly increases with depth.  The water probably will not rush out of the top of such a container unless it contained a substantial proportion of dissolved gases (e.g., CO2 above the equilibrium concentration), but it would definitely rush out of any hole that was below the initial water line.  More detail would definitely be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand the question, so I will make a few assumptions.  A container, under pressure, holds water.  This pressure could presumably be measured, and may result in some slight deformity of the container.  (I am imagining a metal container, under pressure, containing water).  You open a cap, and the pressure is reduced.  But the only change in volume (BECAUSE WATER IS NOT COMPRESSIBLE) is due to the deformation of the container, which could be minimal.  So the answer is: because water in not compressible.